# What unit is the length of a protein measured in?

Tags: proteins, proteomics

Sorry if this question is obvious - I'm not familiar with proteomics so I'm not sure of the standard units.

[In this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2805705/), it talks about using the length of a protein to calculate the NSAF value.  However, it doesn't specify the units.  Would it be peptides, amino acids or nucleic acids? Or something else?

Comment: Number of amino acids.

Comment: The paper clearly states `protein length (number of amino acids)`.

Comment: Isn't this exactly the type of questions we like on this site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by others, it's the number of amino acids. Alternative measurements could be in Angstroms or similar, but that would require at least an approximate structure.